# How to use IdentityManager with AspNetCoreIdentity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identitymanager

is there a chance to user IdentityManager  with an AspNet Core Identity?

I did not find any implementation of IIdentityManagerService for AspNetCoreidentity.

Alternatively, is there any replacement for IdentityManager when using AspnetCore identity?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this out https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html

Comment: @Nkosi: I'm referring to IdentityManager (https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager) which is a SPA application for managing Users, Roles etc.

Comment: Ok my misunderstanding

Comment: Hi @SkorunkaFrantišek I found your repo "https://github.com/skorunka/IdentityManager/" - could you please elaborate on how to implement it? I think I will figure it out, but for the moment I will postpone the implementation and focus on other stuff, I'm building a small demo app for a blog post using .net core, asp .net core and Identity Server on top of .net core Identity.  Thanks :)

Comment: Check https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/master/source/Host/Startup.cs. Instead of "InMemoryIdentityManagerService" use "AspNetCoreIdentityManagerService<TUser,TRole>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use IdentityManager to manage your AspNetIdentity users.

There is an implementation in IdentityManager itself called IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity. You may want to read through [an article describing your scenario by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx).

What you essentially want to do is whereas you load your IdentityManagerService inheriting from the `AspNetIdentityManagerService`

```
public class ApplicationIdentityManagerService : AspNetIdentityManagerService<ApplicationUser, string, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationIdentityManagerService(ApplicationUserManager userMgr, ApplicationRoleManager roleMgr) : base(userMgr, roleMgr)
    {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

You can then plug it in into your factory as such:

```
app.Map("/users", idm =>
{
    var factory = new IdentityManagerServiceFactory();
    factory.IdentityManagerService = new Registration<IIdentityManagerService, ApplicationIdentityManagerService>();
    factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationUserManager>());
    factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationUserStore>());
    factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationRoleManager>());
    factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationRoleStore>());
    factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationDbContext>(resolver => new ApplicationDbContext("dbase")));
    factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationDbContext>());

    idm.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerOptions { 
        Factory = factory
    });
});
```

Find a [more complete example](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity/tree/master/samples/IdMgr_with_AspId) on the [IdentityManager AspNetIdentity GitHub repo](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity).